# What's the least costly way to color tint a texture or rgb value?

Tags: c++, rgb

I'm currently working on a 3D graphics and soon-to-be physics engine, and I've run into a predicament: Tinting texture rgb values really slows down the program. I've tried doing multiply methods, but at the moment, this formula seems to be the fastest (which isn't saying much since it still slows it down quite a bit.)

```
//the 't' stands for texture
unsigned int tr = (col >> 16) & 255;
unsigned int tg = (col >> 8) & 255;
unsigned int tb = col & 255;

//the 'p' stands for polygon color, I divide by 255 to get the color percentage
float pr = ((color >> 16) & 255) / 255.0f;
float pg = ((color >> 8) & 255)/255.0f;
float pb = (color & 255)/255.0f;

//I then multiply the texture pixel by the corresponding brightness percentages
SetPixel(x, y, ((int)(tr * pr) << 16)| ((int)(tg * pg) << 8)| ((int)(tb * pb)));
```

Does anybody have a better formula?

Comment: When we designed a CPU-based renderer in university I actually noticed a speedup when using 1 division and 3 multiplications instead of 3 divisions, i.e. `auto f = 1 / 255.0f; float pr = ((color >> 16) & 255) * f;` ... Maybe that helps. Even better would be to leverage the GPU instead of the CPU, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are invoking a `SetPixel` function on **each pixel** of an image, the function call overhead alone will be a huge impact - especially in non-optimized debug builds. e.g. a 320x320 image is 100K function calls to set each pixel. Even with C++ function inlining and optimizations, it's not always the fastest.

What you want to do is get the raw buffer bytes of the texture and operate on them directly within a single function call. You'll find that makes a huge difference.

Comment: Exactly my first thought.

Comment: Actually don't worry, SetPixel is a function I made that just sets a value in an int array to be drawn to the screen later

Comment: @Humanagon - that's the point. It is a function when it should just be a macro at best. A function call "per pixel" is a performance killer.  Do a benchmark for the following four scenarios. 1) Using your SetPixel function as you have it now in a debug/non-optimized build. 2) Copy your SetPixel code directly where it's needed instead calling it as a function. 3) #1 but in an optimized build  (e.g. -O2 or /O2 compiler flag).  4) #2, but in an optimized build.

Comment: My guess is that you are going to see tremendous performance increases across the board with an optimized build. But eliminating the function call will have an equal amount of impact.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a bug/typo in your code:

```
SetPixel(x, y, ((int)(tr * pr) << 16)| ((int)(tg * pg) << 8)| ((int)(tr * pr)));
                                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

That should be `tb * pb`.

Second, I guess that the slow part is the `SetPixel`, more than the other computations, but anyway. The slow part is the floating point operation. Or really any operation. Can we **precompute**? In this case the answer is yes, since you have 256×256 possibilities. So you can do:

```
int compute2(unsigned int col, unsigned int color)
{
    unsigned int tr = (col >> 16) & 255;
    unsigned int tg = (col >> 8) & 255;
    unsigned int tb = col & 255;

    unsigned int pr = (color >> 16) & 255;
    unsigned int pg = (color >> 8) & 255;
    unsigned int pb = color & 255;

    return (table[tr][pr] << 16) |
        (table[tg][pg] << 8) |
        table[tb][pb];
}
```

What is table? Is an array of 256 arrays of 256 bytes, the result of your operation for one byte times the other divided by 255 and cast to int.

Here is the table (shortened because of the limits on StackOverflow):

```
uint8_t table[256][256] = {
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7},
[...]
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255}
};
```

On [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1v1bzPK1c) the full table with a test.

Comment: thanks for telling me about the typo, I fixed it

Comment: Along time ago I tried optimizing some codec code with table look ups. To my surprise, I found that *math* is actually faster than *memory fetching from an array* in a lot of cases. But it's worth trying...

Comment: @selbie That is totally possible. The best approach is to measure. In this case it seams that [the table is faster than the original approach](https://godbolt.org/z/ndeGrvv39). Notice that we are thrashing the cache here with random accesses. I expect real cases to be even faster.

Comment: @selbie More testing does **not** confirm the result. Check this: https://godbolt.org/z/E5Yzserq4

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Rather than shifting right the texture components, and later shifting left by the same amount, you could just mask out the unwanted bits and work with the scaled values. Anyway, after forming the products, you need to mask out the unwanted bits again.

Another way to split the components is by using a union that maps four bytes over the int. The compiler might use single byte moves rather than arithmetic.

Rather than working with floats, you can arrange to keep integers: instead of `a * (b / 255.)`, use `(a * b) / 255` (another option is to replace the division by `255.` with a product with the inverse, but it is likely that the compiler already does that).

Also consider if dividing by `256` (by a shift) rather than `255` is not a viable option.

---

Generally speaking, divisions by non-powers of two and switching between int and float are performance killers.

---

Possible solution:

```
union { unsigned int packed; struct { unsigned char a, b, g, r; }; } tex, col;
tex.packed= ...;
col.packed= ...;
col.r= (col.r * tex.r) >> 8;
col.g= (col.g * tex.g) >> 8;
col.b= (col.b * tex.b) >> 8;
SetPixel(x, y, col.packed);
```

CAUTION: not tested at all and the component order may be wrong. You'll have to check that.

---

For the picky ones, the exact integer division is obtained by

```
(a * b) / 255 = (a * b * 32897) >> 23
```

for `a`, `b` in `[0, 255]`.

Comment: When 255 is 100% then how is division by 256 useful?

Comment: @ÖöTiib: read my comment "Also consider if dividing by 256 (by a shift) rather than 255 is not a viable option." The error does no exceed 0.4% and will not be visible.